# Agile user stories for AI users?

Tags: agile, user-stories

I understand that agile user stories are for human stakeholders for an app, product; but what if you're making a game (ie: tycoon) where you have AI characters performing actions or third-party entities that interact with the human player.

Do these entities have their own stories?

IE:
As a popcorn vendor I want to be able to ...
As a football shirt sponsor I want to be able to promote my product to last years Champions League Winner

Or am I overcomplicating it?

Thanks

Comment: AI - Artificial Inteligence? Might be better off using the word "virtual" to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: If you have a game where entities interact with the player then simply write from the perspective of the player (i.e. the real user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main objective of any good user stories is define the work and most importantly defines the value of that work.

So whatever situation it is, you will define user stories where the value is driven from the Business. In case of AI, if you believe that AI is running Business and Business is giving you money to build values then you should listen AI. Otherwise listen to whomsoever who is feeding you money (i.e. sponsoring your project).

In terms of entity, yes, AI can be an entity but at the end he has to interact with you and define these user stories. Of course Artificial Intelligence cannot do you for you. So someone is thinking on the behalf of AI.

Thus you can use AI as persona

**What is persona?**
A persona, first introduced by Alan Cooper, defines an archetypical user of a system, an example of the kind of person who would interact with it. The idea is that if you want to design effective software, then it needs to be designed for a specific person. For the bank, potential personas could be named Frances Miller and Ross Williams. In other words, personas represent fictitious people which are based on your knowledge of real users. - See more at: http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/personas.htm#sthash.7ndZPbDx.dpuf

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question but consider the following two points:

1. A user story is a brief description of a **features our customer would want** in his software
2. Business people (of our customer) and developer team must **work together** daily through the project

So AI characters:

1. are really your actual customer?
2. can work daily with you?

Even if you are working on the "tycoon engine" AI characters interact with, so AI might be considered as your customer, I don't think they can work daily with you,[maybe one day with some limitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnzlbyTZsQY).